# ionic 2 call function from another controller

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I need to **call** `function` in **another controller** in `ionic 2`,  it is possible?

below my code and i want to call `loadPeople` in tab controller.

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {PeopleService} from '../../providers/people-service/people-service';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public peopleService: PeopleService) {
   this.loadPeople();
  }

 loadPeople(){
  this.peopleService.load()
  .then(data => {
  this.people = data;
  });
 }

}
```

**tabs.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../contact/contact';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  tab1Root: any = HomePage;
  tab2Root: any = AboutPage;
  tab3Root: any = ContactPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

in **tabs.ts** i want to call `loadPeople` function on **tab selected** , how i can do this ?

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Comment: i've started from https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tabs

Comment: Could you please add more details about the function and what it does? Because the best approach would be to create a shared service and put that method there, so you can call it from everywhere. Does it make sense in the context of your app?

Comment: i've update my question

Comment: not sure about calling from another controller. why not just call `loadPeople()` in `ionViewDidEnter()` life cycle hook in the tab?

Answer (score 18):

There are several options. One way is to put your function `loadPeople()` into a [service class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html), which is accessible from all components.

Another way is to use [Ionic Events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/) to trigger function calls between components.  For example, if the selection of a tab calls a function `tabSelected()`, you can fire an event in this function:

```js
tabSelected() {
  this.events.publish('functionCall:tabSelected', anyAdditionalData);
}
```

and listen to it in `home.ts` and call `loadPeople()` if the event has been fired:

```js
this.events.subscribe('functionCall:tabSelected', eventData => { 
  this.loadPeople();
});
```

You can even send data with the event (here: `anyAdditionalData`).

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to define the function as **static** and call the function with class name.

eg:

```
class A{
 static f1(){
  console.log("funtion1");
 }
}

class B{
  classA.f1();
}
```

Hope it will work